# How to count how many times a value (referral code) appears in a row

Tags: mysql

I have a referral system, email is the referral code it's working but I want to count how many times a value (email) appears in a row as to display to the user how many person he/she have referred.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to implement COUNT(), which will give you the total number that this email string was used:

```
SELECT COUNT(email) FROM table_name WHERE email = 'xxx@gmail.com';
```

or if it is by numeric id:

```
SELECT COUNT(email_id) FROM table_name WHERE email_id = 111;
```

Comment: It will be better to use ``=`` instead of ``like``.

Comment: thanks for the great suggestion, i expanded my answer

Comment: What I meant is to use ``email = 'xxx@gmail.com'`` instead of ``email like 'xxx@gmail.com'`` !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT() function which shows the number of records returned by a select query

```
select email, IFNULL(COUNT(id),0)total_ referred from table where email = 'example@gmail.com';
```